# Importing file fails in Node.js when implementing server side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a implementing server side rendering on React project written in typescript. All the components,containers and other directories are in `src` directory. 
When react imports a file from say `./src/providers/xxProvider.ts` it can simply import it as `import * from "providers/xxProvider"`. I'm guessing this is something done by webpack when bundling.
But now when I'm trying to use Node.js for ssr, node.js cannot find the xxProvider file when its imported as `import * from "providers/xxProvider"` because it starts looking in node_modules.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: just a guess, can you try `import * from "./providers/xxProvider"`. when you use `./` it will not look in node_modules

Comment: @MohitTilwani true this will work. But then I will have to change all the files which are importing any file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The issue is from using the `webpack-node-externals` plugin. When we use that, webpack will automatically ignore the node-modules folder when bundling. 
When I import something as `import * from providers/xxProvider` and at the same time I have a directory in node_modules as providers/xxx, webpack will exclude all directories called `providers` when bundling.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have proper [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) defined in your `tsconfig.json`. Try this for example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```